# Linux - options to establish IPC with second process

Tags: linux, ipc

I am trying to study all the different ways I can find in order for a process on a linux machine to establish IPC with a second process (not a child) on the same machine. I did find that `socket` can be used given I know the path on file system the second process is listening to.

Is IPC communication with an second process possible in other ways ? I don't want the first process to know the pid/uid of the second process. The scenario is more towards communicating with an untrusted process, by a different author, on the same machine, but still have some information like where the socket in the second process is listening ?

Comment: Look for shmat. It will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Shared Memory and Sockets can be used for IPC communications between the processes that are not related to each other. Pipes can be used for IPC communications between the parent and child processes.

Shared memory is the fastest form of interprocess communication. In all other methods, the system calls copy the data from the memory area of one process to another process. The drawback of shared memory is, you need to implement synchronization methods to avoid race condition.

Sockets interfaces enables communication in a connection oriented way between the process across the network as well as locally. UNIX domain sockets provides local IPC using a known file path.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible ways:**

1. Shared memory (`shmget`, `shmctl`, `shmat`, `shmdt`)
2. FIFO queues aka named pipes (`mkfifo`)
3. Message queues (`msgget`, `msgsnd`, `msgrcv`, `msgctl`)
4. Semaphores - for synchronization (`semget`, `semctl`, `semop`)

**Hint:**

Useful commands: `ipcs`, `ipcmk`, `ipcrm`

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use `mmap` POSIX standard call with flag `MAP_SHARED` specified. Here https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/fahmy/cs503/mmap.txt you can find an example of using it.